# How to change the theme colour in salesforce homepage?

Tags: home-page-component, user-interface

Is it possible to change the the User Interface of home page header and sidebar according the the client requests?

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the theme of salesforce, but you can change the image on the left corner according to your application.

And you can work with the older version theme by going to
  setup-> Customize-> UserInterface-> (uncheck) Enable New User Interface Theme.

Comment: ok, The below mentioned video explains it in a detailed manner.                        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uTF3o5UJTs           i have tried in this way but no change was done at my home page........ can u please explain a little more.......